# p4-git bridge for intellij community edition

Tags: git, version-control, intellij-idea, perforce, git-p4

I have community edition of the Intellij. But it supports very few version control systems but my company uses perforce.

Is there any way i can achieve the version control with out manually checking out. And fire some command to submit to the p4.

Basically i am thinking to go with local git repo. And some kind of `p4-git` plugin to submit my changes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this. The best is with [Perforce Git Fusion](http://www.perforce.com/git-fusion), but it does have some infrastructure requirements. Nothing much, but I've found that it's enough to run afoul of ossified corporate bureaucracies. If that happens, you can fall back on [git-p4](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4), which is less capable but is included in the Git distribution and doesn't have any infrastructure requirements.

Finally, I suspect IntelliJ probably does support Perforce. I haven't used it, but I do use PyCharm which does have Perforce support, and Jetbrains' IDEs are basically all the same under the hood.

Comment: IntelliJ does support Perforce, but only in the Ultimate version.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution [git-p4](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git-p4_Usage). It looks very easy and simple.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new open source Perforce plugin for the community edition, [p4ic4idea](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7685), which includes full VCS integration with the IDE.  It's not as robust as the IntelliJ Ultimate Edition supplied Perforce plugin, but it enables the simple add, delete, edit, and submit actions.